# Inconsistent sending and reading of integers via Python serial to an Arduino

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to send Integers via Python and serial communication to an Arduino, read it there, and send it back (solely for debugging) to print via Python.

I am getting often either zeros send back, or the integers in wrong orders. I am hitting the wall. I went back to a minimal example and still can't see my mistake.

Arduino code:

```cpp
uint32_t val1;
uint32_t val2;
uint32_t val3;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read values from Python
    val1 = Serial.parseInt();
    val2 = Serial.parseInt();
    val3 = Serial.parseInt();
  }
  
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // Print received values for reading back to Python
    Serial.println(val1);
    Serial.println(val2);
    Serial.println(val3);
  }
}
```

Python code:

```py
import serial
import time

port = '/dev/cu.usbmodem14301'
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate=115200, timeout=None)

# Wait for Arduino to initialize
time.sleep(2)

#flush input buffer
ser.reset_input_buffer()


# define three parameters/integers to send in a list
numbers = [123, 60000, 789] #max integer is 2^15-1 for normal int in Arduino, we use uint32_t in Arduino, which is an unsigned 32bit -> 2^32-1

# send to Arduino as csv
for num in numbers:
    ser.write(str(num).encode())
    ser.write(b',')  # Send comma as delimiter

# Read the response from Arduino
response = []
for _ in range(len(numbers)):
    data = ser.readline().strip()
    response.append(data.decode())

# Close the serial port
ser.close()

# Print the response
print("Response from Arduino:", response)
```

Also is there a possibility to read the integers from Python only once - outside the loop and declare them globally. I failed at that, too.

Comment: You're testing with two unknowns at once: both sides of the serial link are unproven programs. Simplify the test environment by testing only one program at a time. Replace one end with a terminal emulation program (e.g. PuTTY) and a serial port (USB adapter?).

Comment: Huh? How are they ‘unproven programs’. Of course the communication was checked via i.e. serial plotter. The last thing I would use is putty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino code is faulty. You have a 50% chance that you will write first and then read. Be aware that the char can arrive at any time. Such a change could help it a little. In general, when transferring data, you need some synchronization between both nodes. For example, line feed characters as it is done in the opposite direction.

```
uint32_t val1;
uint32_t val2;
uint32_t val3;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    // read values from Python
    val1 = Serial.parseInt();
    val2 = Serial.parseInt();
    val3 = Serial.parseInt();
    // Print received values for reading back to Python
    Serial.println(val1);
    Serial.println(val2);
    Serial.println(val3);
  }
  
}
```

Comment: That helped! Thank I was assuming sequential execution. The tip with the line feed was excellent, too.